# Multinomial must receive a machine size number

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I need to use the multinomial distribution.

In a certain step, by coincidence, the input probability vector is `{2.6662875218*^-903, 6.180318409067*^-751,  0.5, 6.180318409*^-751, 0.5}`.

When I do

```
RandomVariate[
 MultinomialDistribution[
  1, {2.6662875218*^-903, 6.180318409067*^-751,  0.5, 
     6.180318409*^-751, 0.5}], 1]
```

I get an error message for the values 2.6662875218*^-903, and 6.180318409*^-751, not being machine-size real numbers... When I run my programme on data, the vector of probabilities number of components will be of magnitude of 10^3.

What's the most efficient way to solve this?

Edit: In the above vector, the true values were slightly different. The values 0.5 aren't truly 0.5, since if we sum all the probabilities we must obtain 1. I just changed them to simplify the problem, but I now understand it may induce people into disregarding an important detail. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Threshold` to push these tiny numbers towards `0.` For example,

```
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon/2;
RandomVariate[
 MultinomialDistribution[
  1,
  Normalize[
   Threshold[
    {2.6662875218*^-903, 6.180318409067*^-751, 0.5, 6.180318409*^-751, 0.5}, 
    ϵ
    ],
   Total
   ]
  ], 
 1
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Henrik. However,  one thing that I didn't say, but I thought it was implicit is that the probabilities in the vector must sum to 1. If I just use the threshould, mathematica will realise they don't and stop all computations...

Comment: Ah, I see. `Normalize` can cure the summation problem. Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: Numerical issues tend to be solved with logarithms, so the OP would be using log probabilities. Is that feasible in this case? I doubt it, but it may be worth considering.